# How to Retrieve value from sqlite when passing yyyy-mm to yyyy-mm-dd formated string?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

Hello guys let me explain my problem in detail i have column which saves date value in yyyy-mm-dd format,  Its fine until this what i need is if i pass yyyy-mm alone need to retrieve value of that whole month But i couldn't succeed in it let me post what i have tried so far:

```
 public List<AddNoteModel>activitylist(String date){
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + AddNoteModel.AddNote_Table    + " where " + AddNoteModel.AddNote_ActivityDate   + " LIKE   ' strftime('%Y-%m'," + date +") "  +"%'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        List<AddNoteModel>list=new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String monthname=cursor.getString(0);
                     AddNoteModel staffModel = new AddNoteModel();
                    staffModel.setActivityDate(monthname);
                    list.add(staffModel);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.setNotificationUri(mcontext.getContentResolver(), DB_Timetracker_Staff);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

In that date argument i will pass yyyy-mm Can anyone help me while i try the above method am getting syntax error near %.

Comment: What is the dataType of AddNote_ActivityDate column in SQLite db?

Comment: String in yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: What is this "+"%'";" for at the end of your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add "Like" here try this code instead

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table_name` WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', `your_date_column`) = 'your_formatted_date'
```